# Import conflict when running flask app with apache mod_wsgi on windows

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I am permit you to ask you about a problem that I have with hosting flask application with your portage of mod_wsgi on windows

I have two flask application and only one can be alive a the same times due to conflict in import

ie :
If a request application 1 I have a response 
Then if I request application 2 I have internal server error with error in log ...
Then if I restart apache and I request application 2 I have a response but if I request application 1 I have the same internal server error
If I comments some import like numpy both application can be alive at the same time

Any help would be appreciated if you have any idea or link or answer to about this problem?

My installation is describe below

Thanks by advance for tour times and your works

Alexandre

LOG of the error
    mod_wsgi (pid=4936): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/exec/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi/api_test_2.wsgi'.
    mod_wsgi (pid=4936): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/exec/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi/api_test_2.wsgi'.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/exec/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi/api_test_2.wsgi", line 3, in 
        from api_test_2 import app as application
        File "D:/exec/wsgi_api/api_test_2\api_test_2.py", line 2, in 
            import numpy
        File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in 
            from . import core
        File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in 
            from . import multiarray
        File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in 
            from . import overrides
        File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 46, in 
        """)
     RuntimeError: implement_array_function method already has a docstring

```
#---------------------------------
# file : D:/exec/wsgi_api/api_test_1/api_test_1.py    
#---------------------------------
from flask import Flask, jsonify,render_template, request, make_response
import numpy
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    resp = make_response("hello from 1", 200)
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'charset=utf-8'
    return resp
#---------------------------------        

#---------------------------------
# file : D:/exec/wsgi_api/api_test_2/api_test_2.py    
#---------------------------------
from flask import Flask, jsonify,render_template, request, make_response
import numpy
app = Flask(__name__)    
@app.route('/')
def home():
    resp = make_response("hello from 2", 200)
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'charset=utf-8'
    return resp
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=36000)
#---------------------------------
```

I have this two wsgi file in appache httpdocs

```
#---------------------------------
# file : D:/exec/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi/api_test_1.wsgi
#---------------------------------
import sys 
sys.path.append('D:/exec/wsgi_api/api_test_1/') 
from api_test_1 import app as application
#---------------------------------


#---------------------------------
# file : D:/exec/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi/api_test_2.wsgi
#---------------------------------
import sys 
sys.path.append('D:/exec/wsgi_api/api_test_1/') 
from api_test_1 import app as application
#---------------------------------


#---------------------------------
In D:/exec/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf i add the line
#---------------------------------
WSGIScriptAlias /api_test_1 "D:/exec/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi/api_test_1.wsgi"
WSGIScriptAlias /api_test_2 "D:/exec/Apache24/htdocs/wsgi/api_test_2.wsgi"
#---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in a project. In my case, I had to add `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` inside the `.conf` file of my site.

This is the documentation where I found the information:
https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#sub-interpreter-being-used

Comment: What file exactly are you referring by `.conf` can you please provide the complete path. Thanks!

Comment: And if you meant `httpd.conf` where exactly do I need to add it, which section I mean.

Comment: @lorenzo, I was stuck here for 3 days. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had a discussion on the mod_wsgi mailing list and I had the same response The explanation is numpy doesn't work in Python sub interpreters as the C extension modules are not implement properly to allow that, thus for mod_wsgi you can only use numpy in the main interpreter context, forced by the 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}' directive

This is linked with the subject https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3961

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your WSGI configuration file:

```
single-interpreter = true
```

Comment: The problem is the same on linux.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

i add WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in apache config file which is available in site-enabled folder.